# Photography Stack Exchange tagline

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Does anyone have any ideas for a short, catchy tagline we can use in promoting the Photography Stack Exchange? Something that would get people's attention if we used it for online advertisements and maybe on business cards, stickers and other swag. It can be funny, but try not to make it totally ridiculous, and it should also give people some idea of who we are and what we do.

This can be an ongoing brainstorm; I actually think it's better if we have a bunch of taglines to choose from so that I can customize the ads to the sites I place them on. Please feel free to post ideas here whenever you have them; I'll check back on a regular basis.

Answer (score 12):

Capturing questions, exposing answers.

Comment: Nice and concise and the play on words doesn't feel too forced. I like this one.

Comment: Hmmm... I think 'exposing answers' makes it sounds like said answers are secret or something.

Comment: By popular vote, looks like this one wins. We'll test it out as one of our taglines for online ads.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Well, not necessarily secret...but certainly unknown by the asker. Hence the play on words. ;) I'm surprised this one won...it was kind of a random thought at the time.

Comment: So am I. It sounds like the tagline of an over-enthusiastic school newspaper...

Comment: No need for insults now, Elendil. I didn't choose it, I just recommended it. Everyone who voted chose it.

Comment: @elendil I'll use it for now, but this isn't the "official" tagline for the site or anything. I can use a different tagline for every ad (most online ads can rotate between several different creatives). So keep the ideas coming!

Comment: @jrista: no insult intended, sorry if it came over that way.

Answer (score 7):

Your photography questions answered.

Or variants thereon such as:

Your photography questions answered in a snap.

Comment: I like the second one, perhaps better without the "Your": "Photography questions, answered in a snap"

Answer (score 4):

Developing better answers, one exposure at a time.

Answer (score 2):

"Finally, a photography Q&A site that works."

This was actually proposed by [Jin](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/jin), and it kind of cuts right to the point. Our site get you expert answers, with proof that they're good answers. It's a provocative statement that I think would get people to click ("Who are these people making this claim? Are they actually better?").

Comment: What about "Finally, a photography Q&A site that clicks."

Answer (score 0):

How about:

The focus is on you

Answer (score 0):

RAW Awesomeness (better than JPEG)

Answer (score -6):

Think you know photography? You don't know click.

Comment: I don't like the disparaging tone of this one. I know (from your answers and general attitude!) that you don't mean it, but this sounds like setting up the existing community here as a bunch of entrenched know-it-alls. I hope that's not how we're perceived by new visitors.

Comment: I agree I'm afraid. Plus "don't know click" - is that a play on "don't know dick"? I really don't think that strikes an appropriate tone.

Comment: hahah, you guys are no fun. WHCC uses a similar tag line for some events they host.(WHCC is a printer)

Comment: I tend to agree with mattdm and mark here... and I've seen it on WHCC's tradeshow events, and the put off reaction it generates.